# Getting an item count and joining table to display items customer detail

Tags: mysql, join, count

I have two tables: *customers* *items*

I need to display a query that shows each customers (selling) items total

example:

> customer_name | total_items_customer_selling | customer_address

I have used Count() but keep getting a total value for all items in table

```
SELECT count(id) FROM items GROUP BY items.id
```

also how do i join ? I hope that's specific enough

> structure:
>
> customers(Id(primary), name, address, city, state).
>
> items(Id(primary), description, cost, seller(FK))

hope that explains the structure better

Comment: Please edit your post and add the structure of your two tables. you have to _join_ on these two tables and then _group by_ your _customer id_

Comment: i hope that looks better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT c.Id,  c.Name, COUNT(*) AS Items
FROM Customers AS c
LEFT JOIN Items AS i ON i.Seller = c.Id
GROUP BY c.Id, c.Name
```

Comment: cheers, im going to research up on left join, but what is that or if you know a good resource on joins?

Comment: also say i need to show customers that might not have any transactions in the items list? how do i show this ? so the customer shows but shows 0 in the count (or null).

Comment: I think for _customers that might not have any transactions in the items list_ it;s better to use `exists`. please do some research on it...

Comment: When using a left join to join two tables we are basically saying we want to select all the rows in the table to the left of the join statement and join then to any matching rows in the right table based ON the conditions specified. If a row exits in the left table, but not in the  right then the row will still be returned however any fields from the right table will be null. If more than one matching row exists in the right table this will cause the matching entries on the left table to be duplicated for every match. The sql above should give you counts of 0 for customer that do not have item